# Using the mysql_insert_id function

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a question for using the `mysql_insert_id` function when I want to insert new data from html form into multiple tables?
The form I'm using is this:

```
<form method="POST" action="insert.php">

    <table>

        <tr>
        <td>Room</td>
        <td>
            <select name="room">
            <?php
                openDB();

            $sql = "SELECT room_id, name FROM room";
            $rs = executeDB($sql);

        while(list($room_id, $name) = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    echo "<option value='$room_id'>$name</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Product</td>
        <td>
        <select name="product">

        <?php
        openDB();

        $sql = "SELECT product_id, name FROM product";
        $rs = executeDB($sql);

        while(list($product_id, $name) = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

        echo "<option value='$product_id'>$name</option>";
    }
            ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
<td>Quantity</td>
    <td>
     <?php 
    openDB();

    $sql = "SELECT quantity FROM items_order";
    $rs = executeDB($sql);

        while(list($quantity ) = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

         echo " <input type='number' name='quantity []' min='1' max='4'/></td>";

          }
          ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Then to enter those variables :

```
if(isset($_POST['user'])) {
        $user= $_POST['user'];
        $room_id = $_POST['room_id'];
        $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
        $quantity= $_POST['quantity'];
        $status = 0; // if it's payed or not, if it is status= 1 else status = 0
```

Here is the code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO order (status, room_id, user_id) VALUES ('$status','$room_id','$user_id')";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);

$newid = mysql_insert_id();

$sql2 ="INSERT INTO items_order VALUES ('$newid ','$product_id','$quantity')";
$rs = mysql_query($sql2);
```

and it doesn't work.

The tables I have are; order , items_order, product, the order has order_id primary key as auto increment, 
the items_order has two primary keys: order_id, 
and product_id as they are foreign keys, room has room_id, and the product has product_id,
the foreign keys in order table are user_id, room_id, for. 
Do i have to use that function to enter new data or not?
And most importantly what am I doing wrong that this code doesn't work?
Please help.

Comment: You should specify the language you're using, in particular in the tags.

Comment: I use php the database is in ENGINE=InnoDB.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` to find out whether the queries worked out in the first place; do test outputs to see what's in the variables. This needs more information to be useful.

Comment: What doesn't work is when the user logs in and he places an order for a product, enter his quantity, and chose the room where he want's to sit it doesn't show up in the tables taht a new order has been placed, taht my major problem.

Comment: As said, use the steps above to debug the problem. That's the normal way to fix a problem like this. Here is more info on `mysql_error()`: http://php.net/mysql_error

Comment: Ok will, tried it out and then get back with an answer.

Comment: I used the mysql_error() function but it doesn't show up any errors?

Comment: Ok i did use the function mysql_error() but it doesn't show any errors, what can i do next to resolve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure PHP doesn't use string interpolation, so the strings you see in the program code are actually what it tries to give to MySQL. Obviously that wouldn't work.

The correct way to do this is to use prepared queries where you can substitute the parameters in a safe manner. What you are doing is just an invitation for an SQL injection attack. Of course, the old MySQL extension for PHP doesn't support those, which is why it is deprecated and slated to be removed soon. So you shouldn't use it.

Follow this link and its instructions and learn about the right way to access MySQL in PHP:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: That's even worse. You're learning the wrong thing. If you were working on an existing code base, you probably wouldn't have a choice, but now you do. So please, learn the right way now.

Comment: This is all correct, but how does it address the OP's problem?

Comment: I will, but to pass the exam in college I have to do it like we did on the exercises otherwise  the professor won't let me to take on the exam. I have to make the project with the database that is not quite god, so again can you help me or not?